# I get Argument of \OT1\' has an extra } when I have an accents in the last name (macOS, TeXShop)

Tags: bibtex

I see this problem being reported for other TeX editors, but not for TeXShop, so I will post here.

I prefer to use the `amsalpha` style, but it doesn't seem to like it when there is an accented letter within the first three letters of the author's last name.

One of my entries in my `bib` file has

```
@Article{Des82,
  author =       {J. {D{\'e}sarm{\'e}nien}},
  title =        {Un analogue des congruences de {K}ummer pour les $q$-nombres d'{E}uler},
  journal =      "European J. Combin.",
  year =         {1982},
  volume =    {3},
  number =    {1},
  month =     {},
  pages =     {19--28},
  note =      {},
  annote =    {}
}
```

And this produces an error I wrote in the title. So I go check what's going on with the `bbl` file, and I see the following.

```
\providecommand{\bysame}{\leavevmode\hbox to3em{\hrulefill}\thinspace}
\providecommand{\MR}{\relax\ifhmode\unskip\space\fi MR }
% \MRhref is called by the amsart/book/proc definition of \MR.
\providecommand{\MRhref}[2]{%
  \href{http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=#1}{#2}
}
\providecommand{\href}[2]{#2}
\begin{thebibliography}{{D{\'}}82}

\bibitem[{D{\'}}82]{Des82}
J.~{D{\'e}sarm{\'e}nien}, \emph{Un analogue des congruences de {K}ummer pour
  les $q$-nombres d'{E}uler}, European J. Combin. \textbf{3} (1982), no.~1,
  19--28.

\end{thebibliography}
```

Not hard to see which part is causing issues - `{{D{\'}}82}`. I used `{\'{e}}` but this doesn't help. I would appreciate any help on how to circumvent this issue.

Finally, I changed the style with `amsplain` instead to see what happens, but I didn't like how the reference numbers are in the form `1.` rather than `[1]` in the References list.

Anyway, any help will be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The alphabetic styles are utterly confused when accented letters are present at the beginning of the name. Do you really need this very old-fashioned method? It was used in the olden times of typewriters, when there was no real way to have a sensible numbering scheme in case of changes to the document during its preparation.

Here's a workaround that however will not guarantee correct sorting if there are names too close to Désarménien.

<sup>The `filecontents*` environment is only used for making the example self-contained.</sup>

```latex
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@Article{Des82,
  author =    {J. {D{\es}arm{\'e}nien}},
  title =     {Un analogue des congruences de {K}ummer pour les $q$-nombres d'{E}uler},
  journal =   {European J. Combin.},
  year =      {1982},
  volume =    {3},
  number =    {1},
  month =     {},
  pages =     {19--28},
  note =      {},
  annote =    {}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\e}{\'es}
\newcommand{\es}{\'es}

\begin{document}

\cite{Des82}

\bibliographystyle{amsalpha}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

The problem is that the `amsalpha` style just takes the first three elements of the surname (excluding braces), so in this case you end up with `D\e`. Another workaround could be using `D\es arm\'enien`, so only `\es` would be needed.

[image]

You might use `biblatex`:

```latex
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}
@Article{Des82,
  author =    {J. {D{\'e}sarm{\'e}nien}},
  title =     {Un analogue des congruences de {K}ummer pour les $q$-nombres d'{E}uler},
  journal =   {European J. Combin.},
  year =      {1982},
  volume =    {3},
  number =    {1},
  month =     {},
  pages =     {19--28},
  note =      {},
  annote =    {}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=alphabetic]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\cite{Des82}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

The style of the references can be tweaked in many ways.